# How do I rotate pictures inside their circles on an html 5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I'm trying to make the logos rotating (at a random speed if possible) inside their circles but I can't achieve that.

I tried this:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(0.10);

ctx.drawImage(object.image, object.x-object.size/2, object.y-object.size/2, object.size, object.size);

ctx.restore();
```

But as you can see, the logos are rotating not on their own center.

Pen: https://codepen.io/Le-future/pen/gKNoEE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key thing is to `translate` first, then `rotate`

in `spawnRandomObject`

```
// add the new object to the objects[] array
object.rot = 0;
objects.push(object);
```

in `animate`

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var object = objects[i];
        object.y += object.speed*0.1;
        object.rot += 0.05; // rotation speed

        ctx.globalAlpha = object.opacite;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, object.size/1.25, 0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = object.couleur;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(object.x, object.y);
        ctx.rotate(object.rot);
        ctx.drawImage(object.image, -object.size/2, -object.size/2, object.size, object.size);

        ctx.restore();
    }
```

working fork https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjbeoq

Comment: SUPERSTAR! Exactly what I wanted, +1000 :-)

Comment: Great! If this solves your issue, please consider accepting as answer :)

Comment: Ah yes! Done mate :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to save() at the beginning of the function/iteration and restore() at the end of function/iteration.

I recommend to write a function to draw object:

```
function drawObject(object)
{
  ctx.save()
  object.y += object.speed;

  ctx.translate(object.x - object.size / 2, object.y - object.size / 2);
  object.angle += 0.01; // can be randomized
  ctx.rotate(object.angle);

  ctx.globalAlpha = object.opacite;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, object.size/1.25, 0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = object.couleur;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.drawImage(object.image, -object.size/2, -object.size/2, object.size, object.size);

  ctx.restore();
}
```

You can call it in the loop as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    drawObject(objects[i])
```

or don't write a function, just save() at the beginning of the iteration and restore() at the end.

Another working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBbRJr?editors=0010